# Scraping Information from multiple URLS that are different in structure

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape multiple URLS but they are of different nature, such as different company websites with different html backend. Is there a way to do it without coming up with a customised code for each url?

Understand that I can put multiple URLS into a list and loop them

Answer (score 0):

I fear not, but I am not an expert :-)

I could imagine that it depends on the complexity of the structures. If you want to find a the text "Test" on every website, I coul imagine that `soup.body.findAll(text='Test')` would return all occurences of "Test" on the website.

I assume you're aware of how to loop through a list here, so that you'd loop through the list of URLS and for each check whether the searched string occurs (maybe you are looking for sth else , i.e. an "apply" button or "login" ?

all the best,